# Is big-O notation a tool to do best, worst, & average case analysis of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Is big-O notation a tool to do best, worst, & average case analysis of an algorithm?
Or is big-O only for worst case analysis, since it is an upper bounding function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Big O, because orders of magnitude are expressed like O(n), O(logN), etc.

The best, worst, and average cases of an algorithm can all be expressed with Big O notation.

For an example of this applied to sorting algorithms, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Note that an algorithm can be classified according to multiple, independent criteria such as memory use or CPU use.  Often, there is a tradeoff between two or more criteria (e.g. an algorithm that uses little CPU may use quite a bit of memory).

Comment: Big Omega is typically used to denote lower bounds, ie best case running time, not Big O .. i forget what average is, i think it may just be ~O(fn) iirc..

Comment: @hexist: No, big Omega is used to denote an asymptotic lower bound of a *function*, not an algorithm. For example quicksort is `Theta(nlogn)` average case (and thus `O(nlogn)`) while it is `Theta(n^2)`  worst case (and thus also `Omega(n^2)`). (In other words, big O, big Omega and Theta can all be applied to any analysis)

Comment: @amit hmm, my understanding is that function and algorithm can be used interchangeably in this context, and that Theta notation is used to denote that the function is bounded above and below by the given function (ie the best and worst cases are bounded by some constant multiples of the given function). Canonically speaking, if your function/algorithm has vastly different orders of operation, such as it usually runs in constant time, but sometimes goes to n^2, you would say that it's Omega(1), ~O(1), but sometimes O(n^2). In this case it doesn't have a Theta function since Omega(1) != O(n^2).

Comment: @hexist this confusion is common but still wrong. big Theta,Omega and O are used to denote classes of *functions* and different analysis are used to distinguish between worst/best/average/amortized/... cases. Any of O,Theta,Omega can be used to each of them. Remember that the *definition* of big O is purely speaking about functions - and how to tell if a function is big O or not. No reason not to apply this definition to any of the analysis we use. As for your example, you could say the algorithm is Theta(1) *best case*, and `Theta(n^2)` *worst case* - if you can prove it of course.

Answer (score 1):

Big "O" is a measure of *asymptotic complexity*, which is to say, roughly how an algorithm scales as N gets really large.

If best & worse converge to the same asymptotic complexity, you can use a single value - or you can figure them out seperately (for example, some sorting algorithms have completely different characteristics on sorted or almost-sorted data than on un-sorted data).

The notation itself doesn't convey this though, how you use it does.

---

> ... Or is big-O only for worst case analysis ...

If you give just one asymptotic complexity for an algorithm, it doesn't tell the reader whether (or how) the best and worst case differ from the average.

If you give best-case and worst-case complexity, it tells the reader how they differ.

By default, if a single value is listed, it is probably the average complexity which may (or may not) converge with the worst-case.

Comment: Not really, but I'll address it more directly. If you want 3 bits of information, you need to give 3 bits of information - big O notation is suitable for each part.